# Importing moment-timzone and moment-range with webpack (Babel/ES6)

Tags: javascript, momentjs, ecmascript-6, webpack

I'm using Webpack with Babel loader. Writing by ES6 standards. I have installed both moment-timezone and moment-range with npm.

Both of these are moment.js plugins, and both of these depend on the **moment** package, and export a separate **moment** library. So when I do

```
import moment from 'moment-timezone';
import moment2 from 'moment-range';
```

then I get two separate references to **moment**.

How can I set it up so I could use **moment** with timezone and range functions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 44):

[Docs](https://github.com/gf3/moment-range#installation) show CommonJS syntax for this:

```
var moment = require('moment');
require('moment-range');
require('moment-timezone');

// moment() now has both range and timezone plugin features
```

In ES6:

```
import moment from 'moment';
import 'moment-range';
import 'moment-timezone';
```

*EDIT*

Since `moment-timezone` does not extend existing import but does extend `moment` itself, what about this?

```
import moment from 'moment-timezone';
import 'moment-range';
```

Comment: I have no idea if your answer actually fixes the problem, but either way it is perfectly writable as ES6 imports too.

Comment: Sadly, it does not work in this case. import 'moment-timezone'; does not modify a previously imported "moment". However import 'moment-range'; does. So the problem seems to be with the "moment-timezone" package. I'll give you an upvote, but not checking "correct anwser"

Comment: No, i'm sorry. I tried all the combinations. It has to be done the way you originally suggested (and thanks for that, did not know that syntax for import), but it doesn't work. Somehow "moment-range" only extends moment if i only import "moment". It's strange though. They both depend on the same version of "moment" and I even defined "peerDependencies": {"moment": "2.10.3"} in package.json. So I know i'm getting the same "moment" library for both "timezone" and "range"

Answer (score 12):

I had myself this problem with different packages: `moment-timezone` and `frozen-moment`. The root of all evil is having two `moment` dependencies in different parts of the tree. In my case, I had `moment` right under `node_modules` and also inside of `frozen-moment`'s `node-modules`. This meant that `moment-timezone` and `frozen-moment` were using different `moment` instances.

Check that you are using versions of packages that are compatible with each other so that `moment-range` doesn't need to fetch a different version of `moment`. When you have it correctly you should be able to do this:

```
import moment from 'moment';
import momentTimezone from 'moment-timezone';
import momentRange from 'moment-range';

console.log(moment === momentTimezone === momentRange); // logs 'true'
```

Keep in mind that's only for testing it's properly setup, you should use it like in glortho's answer:

```
import moment from 'moment';
import 'moment-timezone';
import 'moment-range';
```

Comment: I could not import moment-timezone@0.5.14 with moment@2.20.1. However, changing moment to 2.18.1 fixed it for me. I used the recommended syntax: import moment from 'moment';
import 'moment-timezone';
import 'moment-range';

Answer (score 3):

All the above solutions did not work for me and I had to resort to this:

```
import moment from 'moment';
window.moment = moment;
import {extendMoment} from 'moment-range';
extendMoment(window.moment);
```

A little hacky but works.

Answer (score 1):

I find the default implementation of moment-range pretty ugly, since it just extends the moment object, and IMO that's kinda "hacky".

This is the way I'm doing it:

```
import { default as DateRange } from 'moment-range';

const myRange = new DateRange(x, y);
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to import `moment-timezone` and `moment-range` with this code:

```
import Moment from 'moment-timezone';
import momentRange from 'moment-range';

const moment = momentRange.extendMoment(Moment);
```

Answer (score 1):

My project uses webpack with ES6 (same as OP I think), with React. I need functionality from moment timezone. After adding both `moment` and `moment-timezone` npm dependencies, this import statement works:

```
import moment from 'moment-timezone';
```

That allows me to make calls like `moment.tz.guess();`

What really threw me off though- just adding that import doesn't make `moment` available in my browser's dev console. Going through the comments in https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/2608, someone mentioned this snippet which makes `moment` available in the dev console:

```
window.moment = moment;
```

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me

```js
import * as moment from 'moment-timezone'
import * as momentRange from 'moment-range'
```